# How should I set up a Rails app so that some Objects are linked to others (belong_to) but not all Objects have this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I'm not sure whether I've accurately reflected my aim in the title, but I'll explain more here.

In my app I have Companies, and Companies has_many Key_Contacts.

Companies also has_many Sales_Opportunities.

I would like the user to be able to select some of the Key_Contacts that belong_to the Company and associate them with a specific Sales_Opportunity. I would also like the user to be able to add a Key_Contact that is not associated with any Sales_Opportunity.

The aim for this is that I can show the specific Key_Contacts that are involved in one Sales_Opportunity view on the Sales_Opportunity page, but not all of them.

Is it as simple as adding a sales_opportunity_id to the Key_Contacts model, but not setting up the "belongs_to" and "has_many" relationships? Or is there a more "official Rails" method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this right, then all you need to do is add another `has_many :key_contacts` relation to your SalesOpportunity model (and `belongs_to :sales_opportunity` in your KeyContacts model). Then relate all contacts belonging to a specific sales opportunity.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but then I would need to ensure every key_contact is associated with a sales_opportunity, and this may not be the case (some users may want to upload contacts before they establish a sales opportunity for it). It may just be easiest for me to put a column on key_contacts for the sales_opportunity_id, and make it optional for a user to link the two.

Comment: Not every key contact would have to be associated with a sales opportunity. Leaving the sales_opportunity_id field as nil in the key_contacts table is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. That's the route I will take. I appreciate your answer.